# What is the body density of insects on average?

Tags: zoology, entomology, ecology

What is the body density (in $\text{g}/\text{cm}^3$) of insects and is there a list of animals and their value of body density?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A recent study<sup>a</sup> measured the volumes (using a 3D scanner) and dry masses of 113 different insect species. They found the following relationship between the dry mass of the insects and their volumes ($V[mm^3]$ and $m[mg]$):

$\ln (V) = 1.019 \ln (m) + 1.46$

$\Leftrightarrow V = 4.30596 m^{1.019}$

Thus, since $\rho = \frac m V$

$\rho(m) = \frac m {4.30596 m^{1.019}} = \frac {0.232236} {m^{0.019}}
 $

**Figure:** Scatter plot of the measured dry masses and volumes

[image]

**Reference:**

<sup>a</sup> Kühsel, S., Brückner, A., Schmelzle, S., Heethoff, M. and Blüthgen, N. (2016), Surface area–volume ratios in insects. Insect Science. [doi:10.1111/1744-7917.12362](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1744-7917.12362/full)

Comment: On the graph the Volume is in $mm^2$ $\ddot \smile$ So the density is a decreasing function of the mass. Below, 0.2 grams, the density becomes very important. To make the graph in R: `f=function(m) {0.0346737 / (m^1.34633)}; x = seq(0.01,20,0.01); plot(x=x,y=f(x), log='x', ylab="density (mg / ml)", xlab="Body mass (mg)")`

Comment: @Remi.b I did not make this graph, it's from the study. Yes, the density function graph is a hyperbola.

Comment: Of course. I just wanted to comment on this 'weirdosity' and to offer a code to display the relationship you describe.

Comment: @adjan
Thank you. I am new to this site. this was a very cool answer! Do I give gold to the best reply how does this work? (:
I am not very good with math, how do I, if possible, convert the value to a   g/mm3 or a cublic number?

Comment: @AndreasJørgensen If you find an answer helpful, upvote using the arrow up button. Additionally, you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark icon. The function gives density in $\frac {mg}{mm^3}$, so just multiply with $10^3$ to get $\frac g {mm^3}$.

Comment: *Divide by $10^3$.

Comment: $$\log_{10} V= 1.019\log_{10} m+1.46 \rightarrow \log v-\log 28.8403= \log m^{1.019}\rightarrow \log V/28.8403 = \log m^{1.019} \rightarrow V = 28.8403 m^{1.019}.$$ Where does 2.34633 come from?

Comment: @daniel from mistakenly assuming my calculator's $\log$ was $\log_{10}$, not $\ln$.

Comment: Can anyone clarify why it says: "volume (mm^2)" on the y-axis and not "volume (mm^3)" ?

Comment: @AndreasJørgensen i guess it's a typo. there are four charts on that page of this paper, two of them are about area ($mm^2$)

Comment: @AlexDeLarge If you had read the edit comment you'd have known that this is a current SE bug and it makes no sense to change all HTML sup's on SE because it just got broken *today*. I used it in many of my previous answers and the bug only occured today. Wait till the SE team has fixed it!

Comment: Uups, must have overlooked that, my bad. I was not aware of that! Sorry. :) I'll delete my comment.

Comment: It seems that the maths does not match the plot: The $\log$ should be the $\ln$ (natural log, basis e), then the derived formulas indeed describe the data from the plot. Otherwise the formula yields a volume which is approximately a factor 6.7 too high.

Comment: @DominikS I think now it should be correct

Answer (score 1):

I did the following estimate, based on the honey bee, to get an idea of the order of magnitude of the density of insects: According to [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westliche_Honigbiene#K.C3.B6rperbau) (sorry for the german), we have:

- The average mass of a honeybee is about 80 mg.
- The length is 12 mm in average.

In order to estimate the volume, I model the body in three parts (see [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westliche_Honigbiene#/media/File:Sch%C3%A9ma_abeille-tag.svg) again):

- The head as a sphere with a diameter of roughly 2.5 mm
- The torso as a sphere with a diameter of roughy 4 mm
- The abdomen as a cylinder of length 6 mm, and a diameter of 4 mm.

This will yield a very rough estimate of the volume, but we can expect it to have the correct order of magnitude. It is:

$$ V \approx \pi \cdot\Big (\frac 43\cdot \Big(\frac {2.5}2\Big)^3 +\frac 43\cdot \Big(\frac {4}2\Big)^3  +\Big(\frac 42\Big)^2\cdot 6\Big)\approx 117\text{ mm}^3 $$.

We have not accounted for antennae, legs, ..., so given the uncertainties of my estimates, the volume of a honeybee should be in the range of 100-200 mm^3. This is also in accordance with the graph in @adjan's answer.

With this the density of a honeybee should be between 80/200 and 80/100 mg/mm^3, so $$0.4\,\frac{\text{mg}}{\text{mm}^3} < \rho <0.8\,\frac{\text{mg}}{\text{mm}^3}$$,

which is interestingly slightly less than the density of water.